# What is the best way to include external components in a respository

Tags: git, svn, version-control

A very common situation I have come about many times with no nice solution is how to share code between projects. The case is typically that you have a number of projects that needs to share some small amount of code. Often that code is contained in header files and consists mostly of struct-definitions which define how communication between the projects looks. These communication protocols evolve during development of the projects and needs to be under revision control.

How should this be done for the different version control systems? I know SVN has externals which almost solves this, but you will have the issue of dealing with different revisions between the different projects.

The even trickier question is, how should this be done between different versioning systems, say one project in GIT and one in SVN?

Comment: This is not a full answer, but a good solution to the Git-SVN problem is to avoid it; use all Git or all SVN.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, you are right of course. But it is not always possible, and how to handle it in those situations?

Comment: Look into using Git submodules.  You could create a submodule which contains code from an SVN project.